# @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with name of foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Under hibernate-jpa-api-2.0, can i specify the name of the foreign key using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn with oneToOne relation ?

I tried the folowing but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CARID")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_CAR_CORP")
public CarEntity getCar() {
    return car;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two `@ForeignKey` annotations can be used:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey (Hibernate annotation)
javax.persistence.ForeignKey (JPA annotation)
```

Hibernate 4 (even the last version) sometimes doesn't process, probably cause of bug, `javax.persistence.ForeignKey` annotation.

For example, with Hibernate 4.3.11 we should use `org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey` on the `@OneToMany` part of unidirectional association. And we can use `javax.persistence.ForeignKey` on the `@ManyToOne` part of bidirectional association.

So you can try to use Hibernate `org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The mappedBy attribute is only necessary for a bidirectional relationship, this element can be omitted on the annotation. It is used on the source entity to point back to a field on the target entity that defines the relationship (contains @JoinColumn).

The @JoinColumn annotation should be placed upon the billSimpleEntry field to define the column that should be used to join the two tables. In the case of a OneToOne the following applies:

If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source entity or embeddable.
Here is a code example:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="id") // use actual column name
private ClassName className; // use class name
```

Comment: He wants to specify the NAME of the FOREIGN KEY. as in what is used for schema generation "ADD CONSTRAINT ...". Your answer is NOT that.

Comment: The PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation specifies a primary key column that is used as a foreign key with a generic name to join with the other table, but i want to use more familiar name for the FK constraint

Answer (score 0):

I don't think @ForeignKey will work for hibernate-jpa-api-2.0, as per doc it's release in 2.1

```
Since:
    Java Persistence 2.1
```

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html) is doc

Comment: ok thanks @Bhushan Uniyal, i will find another way maybe using embedded entity